# MVC4 - Display more information about error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using "HttpResponseExpection" to throw exception messages. On exception, trying to display error content and ReasonPhrase, but it is showing only error status code.
Posted the code that i am using to display message.

```
                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No Product with ID = {0}", id)),
                    ReasonPhrase = "Product ID Not Found",
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden

                }; throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```

Code from index.cshtml

```
    function find() {

        clearStatus();

        var id = $('#productId').val();

        $.getJSON(API_URL + id,
        function (data) {
            viewModel.Name(data.Name);
            viewModel.Category(data.Category);
            viewModel.Price(data.Price);
        })
    .fail(
        function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#status').html('Error: ' + err );
        });

    }
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

The `responseText` property of the `jqXHR` object will contain the error message (`Content` property):

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

And if you wanted to get the `ReasonPhrase` property then use the `err` parameter:

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    alert(err);
});
```

Also make sure that you are using the proper status code 404 (`HttpStatusCode.NotFound`) instead of 403 (`HttpStatusCode.Forbidden`) on your API controller:

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No Product with ID = {0}", id)),
    ReasonPhrase = "Product ID Not Found",
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
}; 
throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```